# Collection of custom Apocalypse World moves, with feedback?

Tags: apocalypse-world

For the Hardholder in my *Apocalypse World* game, I thought of a custom move and would now like to share it and in particular get feedback on it.

Also, I'd like to see if somebody else has thought of something similar, and be inspired by other people's custom moves.

Is there a canonical place where *Apocalypse World* (and related hacks, like *Dungeon World*) custom moves are collected, preferably allowing searching, sorting, rating and feedback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best places I've found for this are the <s>Story Games forums</s>, the official [Apocalypse World forums](http://apocalypse-world.com/forums/index.php), and the <s>Apocalypse World G+ group</s>.

Comment: You might want to check the G+ community.  It's a bit more real-time than forums, so it may be closer to what you're looking for, although, truthfully, the forums are very active.

Comment: @Anaphory Hacking moves is halfway between the "consumer" and "designer" side, so there's really never going to be a "splatbook" of custom moves. Embrace the culture of the game, drink the koolaid, and you'll probably find that the benefits of thinking on the designer side of the game is worth it. :)

Comment: FWIW, the forum in the first link and the two other links in your answer are dead.

Comment: Story games closed down, as did G+.  The other one should be live, but is apparently experiencing technical difficulties.

Answer (score 5):

The hacking forums for Apocalypse World are hosted at Apocalypse-World.com as the evocatively-named [Barf Forth Apocalyptica](http://apocalypse-world.com/forums/). That's the hub of *World hacks, homebrews, and analysis.

Comment: FWIW, your link is dead

Comment: @Someone_Evil Hm. That’s still the link from the (working) front page, so my bet is Vincent is just having some issues with the forum software, hopefully temporary.